siunitx column entry causing overfull hbox
I like how I've formatted the following table in TeXLive 2024.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}\centering
    \caption{Bad approximations to $10\pi$}
\begin{tabular}{c S[table-format=2(2), uncertainty-mode = separate]}\hline
Method & Approximation \\\hline % edited in
Method 1 & 27(10) \\
Method 2 & 36(7) \\
Method 3 & 34(3) \\
Almost true value & 31.4 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}


Unfortunately, the .4 is causing Overfull \hbox (7.7778pt too wide).  If I compile the same in TeXLive 2023, I don't get the Overfull, but the output is slightly different (the uncertainties aren't right aligned):

Comparing \listfiles, I see the following differences:



File
2024
2023




siunitx.sty
2024-02-15
2023-06-12


ltxcmds.sty
2023-12-04
2020-05-10


array.sty
2023/10/16
2022/09/04


l3backend-pdftex.def
2024-02-20
2023-04-19



Is there a way to avoid the Overfull hbox, but still have the output I want?  Or should I just ignore the notice?  I've tried {31.4} and 31{.4}, but that causes dramatically different output.
Edit: A complication I did not expect is that the header for the column in question is wider than the numbers, causing problems with the existing answers (+1 to both): Zarko's entries end up left aligned, while egreg's second solution is no longer aligned at all.

Well, shouldn't it be 2.1(2)? If it isn't a number that should be formatted like the rest of the column … how should it?

@Qrrbrbirlbel Since 31.4 is an exact(ish) value, it doesn't need uncertainty.  Since the uncertainty is so large on the others, they don't need the decimal portion, and I'd rather not leave space for an unused decimal portion.  I'm happy with how TL2024 formats the table, with the (sometimes non-existant) decimals aligned, so that I can look through the values at a glance and see how they compare.  But I would also like to avoid the Overfull hbox warning and get that same output.

This appears to do the job:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}\centering
    \caption{Bad approximations to $10\pi$}
\newbox\widest
\setbox\widest=\hbox{\num[uncertainty-mode=separate]{27(10)}}
\begin{tabular}{c S[table-format=2(2), uncertainty-mode=separate]}\hline
Method & {Approximation} \\\hline
Method 1 & 27(10) \\
Method 2 & 36(7) \\
Method 3 & 34(3) \\
Almost true value & {\makebox[\wd\widest][l]{31.4}}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

The downside is that it requires knowing the widest entry of the column.  I suppose it would be possible to automate finding that, but it seems overkill for three entries.

The last entry is special with respect to the others, so you can treat it as such. I give two suggestions, I'd prefer the first one.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  c
  S[table-format=2(2), uncertainty-mode = separate]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Method 1 & 27(10) \\
Method 2 & 36(7) \\
Method 3 & 34(3) \\
Almost true value & \num{31.4} \\
Almost true value & \multicolumn{1}{l@{}}{\num{31.4}} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Bad approximations to $10\pi$}

\end{table}

\end{document}


With the added header, the centering the approximated value in the last row is the only choice.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  c
  S[table-format=2(2), uncertainty-mode = separate]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Method & {Approximation} \\
\midrule
Method 1 & 27(10) \\
Method 2 & 36(7) \\
Method 3 & 34(3) \\
Almost true value & \num{31.4} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Bad approximations to $10\pi$}

\end{table}

\end{document}



An unexpected complication: the header for that column is wider than the entries.  Do you have a fix?

@Teepeemm You're not showing any column header, are you?

I didn't have a column header in my MWE.  My actual code does have a column header.

@Teepeemm How am I going to help if you don’t tell what the header is?

I've edited the column headers into the original post.  I appreciate the help.

@Teepeemm I added how to do it. In my opinion, it makes no sense to align “31” with the numbers in the rows above.

Like this:

With use of the tabularray package you can obtain this with the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\centering
    \caption{Bad approximations to $10\pi$}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={c Q[l, si={table-format=2(2), 
                                  uncertainty-mode = separate}]},
             row{Z} = {guard}
            }
Method 1 & 27(10)   \\
Method 2 & 36(7)    \\
Method 3 & 34(3)    \\
Almost true value & 31.4
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}

Compilation gives:
Errors: 0   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
